# How do I change the server name/machine name portion of a user in the SQL Server sysadmin role?

Tags: sql-server, roles

I created a virtual machine and installed Windows Server 2016 and `SQL Server 2019` on it. After that (without thinking) I changed the name of the virtual machine from `foo` to `bar` so it is descriptive of its role (instead of keeping the random `foo` name that Windows assigns).

Afterward, I was installing other software that uses the database which caused me to review the `sysadmin` role Role Members. At this time, I noticed the local machine administrator entry still included the original machine name, i.e. `foo\administrator`

So, without have to uninstall + reinstall SQL Server, how do I change the `sysadmin SQL Server role member` from `foo\administrator` to `bar\administrator`?

Answer (score 0):

To change the `sysadmin SQL Server role member` from `foo\administrator` to `bar\administrator`, run this command as admin in a CMD console window:

`sqlcmd -E -S "bar" -Q "ALTER LOGIN [foo\Administrator] WITH NAME = [bar\Administrator]"`